# Is there a way to remove all the special characters from a mysql result set using Python and paramiko?

Tags: python, mysql, paramiko

The script I'm using to gather date is listed here. It works, but the output file has way too many junk characters for me to be able to work with correctly.

```
import paramiko
import os

savefile = 'dump.sql'
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(
        paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('123.34.4.4',username='jlefler',password='paSSw0rd')

def sqlcheck(cmd):
        out = []
        msg = [stdin,stdout,stderr] = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
        for item in msg:
                try:
                        for line in item:
                                out.append(line.strip('\n'))
                except: pass

        return(list(out))

dump = sqlcheck('mysql -h database -u user -ppassword database -e "select user_id from users limit 50"')

file = open(savefile, 'w')
file.write(str(dump))
file.close()
print 'The dump had '+str(len(dump))+ ' lines and was saved to '+str(os.path.realpath('dump.sql'))
```

My output files looks like this:

```
[u'user_id', u'\\name1VO', u' name2', u' name3', u'Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.']
```

Is there any way I can utilize paramiko and Python to just download the normal file without any of the odd formatting? I'd like to be able to utilize this for multiple queries, and mysqldumps - but I can't do that if I can't retain the formatting.

Comment: So what do you want to do instead?  Do you want to strip out a certain set of characters completely, or replace them with some substitution?

Comment: I would like the data to present itself like it would taking a normal dump on a server. Is that possible?